# "Атмосферный" и "антуражный" по отношению к часам

Tags: значение-слов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сказать об этих часах, что они антуражные, атмосферные? Или эти слова подходят для описания скорее пространств, помещений, миров и т. п.?

P. S. Я догадываюсь, что неправильно понимаю слово "антуражный". Оно не означает в числе прочего "с особенным, эффектным, характерным антуражем"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Атмосферный — тот, в чём есть какая-то ощутимая атмосфера. Это применимо к спектаклям, фильмам, особенно к видеоиграм. К каким-то действиям во времени. Но к предметам редко. Для этого предмет должен создавать очень сильные эмоции и атмосферу (влиять на сознание своим внешним видом) и быть крайне необычным. В данных часах такой особенности не вижу.

Антуражный — относящийся к антуражу (созданию фона, окружения). Антуражная терапия — смена обстановки. Антуражная бригада — занимающаяся сменой обстановки.

Термин `антураж` обычно используется как понятие в искусстве — в литературе, кино, а также в оформительстве и дизайне.

Если данные часы являются частью какого-то стиля дизайна, то думаю, что их можно назвать антуражными.

Answer (score 1):

Атмосферный - создающий атмосферу, комплекс ощущений, эмоций. Можно также использовать по отношению к предметам.

Понятие "атмосферный" довольно субъективно. Если эти часы воздействуют на вас и вы себе при этом что-то представляете - то они для вас атмосферные.

Антуражный — относящийся к антуражу (созданию фона, окружения).

Кажется, что рисунок на часах очень сочетается с обоями. То есть эти часы антуражны по отношению к обоям.

Comment: Антуражность подразумевает некое соответствие идее, другому предмету? Ведь не может же быть, чтобы только одни часы составляли фон? Я себе, например, представляю, как где-нибудь в театре вывешенные часы являются единственной деталью бэкграунда, привлекающей зрителя. И еще: все-таки антуражность подразумевает атмосферность?

Comment: >"*некое соответствие идее*" --- обязательно, это и есть суть этого слова. >"*антуражность подразумевает атмосферность*" --- да: антураж - это дизайн, а в любом дизайне есть атмосфера. Антураж - совокупность окружающих условий, окружающая обстановка. Часов явно мало. А вот обои с часами - это уже может быть простой декорацией к фотосъёмке.

Comment: Может слово "антуражный" означать "с красивым, выразительным антуражем" (например "антуражное место")?

Comment: Думаю, что да, как и с "атмосферный".